# Split a plane into two triangular faces

Tags: mesh

Adding a plane in Blender (version 3) results in a mesh with one face. How can I split this face into two triangular faces?

Comment: Go into _Edit Mode_ by pressing _Tab_, select the face (but it should be selected by default if you just added the plane) and press _Ctrl+T_ to triangulate the face. Or select two vertices in corners opposite to each other and press _J_ to split the face between those vertices.

Comment: Yep, thanks @GordonBrinkmann!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three (...or maybe more) options:

1. By using the modifier `Triangulate`

   [image]
2. Or you triangulate the mesh in `Edit Mode` with `Triangulate Faces`

   [image]
3. Or mark two diagonally opposite points, and use `Connect Vertex Path` (<kbd>J</kbd>, *thanks to Gordon Brinkman/Crantisz*)

   [image]

Comment: Third option in comments by Gordon

Comment: @Crantisz Thanks, now the answer is complete ;-)

Comment: As long as we're reaching for all the ways to do it:  You can use the knife tool to accomplish the same thing as option 3. ;)